# future imaginary

Tags: sentence

My daughter is 4 yrs of age. She has delivered a small speech in front of lots of people. So, how can I better say the following:

> "If she was grown up she would hesitate and wouldn't be able to do so."

Comment: Your query sentence is confusing. It doesn't say exactly what it is your daughter won't be able to do when she is grown up. Do you mean "If she was grown up she would hesitate and be unable to make that speech"?

Comment: I don't think you meant future at all. "If she was grown up, she would **have hesitated** and wouldn't **have been** able to do so." -- is that what was meant?

Comment: @Araucaria - could you give me a hint why is "was" perfectly correct here?

Comment: @Kris: I think strictly speaking that would be *If she **had been** grown up...* Or the even more strictly correct "subjunctive" *If she **would have been** grown up* - which I find awkward, particularly when *would* isn't contracted to **'d**. It's a declining usage, but in OP's context many people would still use subjunctive ***were*** rather than ***was***. It somewhat depends on whether the speaker wishes to reference what she would have done *on that specific occasion in the past*, or on *any* similar occasion in the (currently, hypothetical) past *or* future.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - would the form "If she *were* grown up.." be erroneous?

Comment: @CopperKettle: If you were me you probably wouldn't think so! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers but according to [this discussion](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20336/as-if-she-were-vs-as-if-she-had-been) I'm reading now is seems that *had been* is the correct choice, not *were*.

Comment: @CopperKettle: As I said, it depends on whether you're referring to what the situation *would have been, **on that specific occasion in the past***, or simply making a "non-time-specific" reference to a hypothetical reality that didn't / doesn't / might not ever come to pass.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You have this fancy for getting tied up in knots for nothing, swe..eet. :)

Comment: @Kris: I'd have thought most native speakers would distinguish *"If I'd been you..."* from *"If I **were** you..."* on that basis. You'd normally only use the "hypothetical past perfect" in references to an *actual* past (which *could have been* different), whereas the subjunctive just applies to any unspecified/unreal time. *"If I were you I'd shoot myself right now"* is fine, but *"If I **had been** you I'd shoot myself right now"* definitely sounds a bit weird to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The *were* suggests contractafactuality, not hypotheticity, though.

Comment: @Kris: *If I **were** to win the lottery tomorrow*, I would demand my winnings cheque. I wouldn't be fobbed off by anyone telling me my win was always inherently contrafactual (so it could never *actually* happen! :)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the original is clear to me, if the sentence is somewhat awkward. You could try a rewrite, such as "An older girl might hesitate and be unable to perform."

Comment: I seriously believe rephrasing is not a solution but running away from a challenge, what do you think? :)